# Hit url in phone browser and launch play store apps in phone with app details

Tags: android

We hit the market place url on phone browser and it open play store inside phone browser but we want to open a Play store app in phone.

Please suggest any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have set default as Browser for opening links.
First clear defaults in settings of Browser. Then try again , it should give you a pop up with Browser and PlayStore as option.

Comment: Thanks for replay, We do not want to clear the default browser setting. Actually I got a link which is already do the same task as my requirement and it will not clear the browser history and directly open the install app page in playstore. The link is http://get.conneckto.com/play-tictactoe-refsa